# GET http://localhost:3000/public/frontpage.png 404 (Not Found) (Image)

Tags: html, node.js, nunjucks

I have problem with my site, I'm trying to upload an image but it's giving me that error.
I don't know how to fix it, can anyone help me?

Here's the error:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post your relevant code and error in your question itself rather than linking to images.  Images can't be searched later.

Answer (score 2):

In your code:

```
server.use(express.static('public'));
```

This effectively means that `/` will be loaded from `public`.  If you want `/public` instead, you need:

```
server.get('/public', express.static('public'));
```